# How to hear Anahata sound during meditation?

Tags: meditation

Anahata sound hearing in mediation? How is the sound? Is it OM kara? Anybody heard the sound during meditation with mantra?

Comment: You can hear the sound when Kundalini crosses Anahata. Its not OM kara. om sound is Pranava which is in higher stages!

Comment: Delete it... and check with Gurus. Not here

Comment: You should not yourself try to hear it, for it may cause illusions, when in deep meditation, it may manifest itself. So its better to do these kinds of  things under the guidance of Guru. Please read Swami Vivekananda's Raja Yoga

Comment: And also read this                                                      


https://isha.sadhguru.org/in/en/wisdom/article/anahata-chakra-take-explore-anahata

Comment: Anahata means??

Comment: @KrishnaShweta Anahata is one of the seven Chakras in the body. It is also called the Heart Chakra and is green in colour. It is the fourth Chakra from the base of the spine.